# What TTS to use on android app using kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

So i am making some basic app in KIVYMD, that i will convert to android apk.

My question is what kind of Text to speech module should i use, Ive been trying pyttsx3 and it was working well on my pc but i saw its not the best for android apk.

Now im trying to use plyer, but i have no idea becasue its not much about tts in docs.

Can i change voice or speed?

I couldnt check that module on my pc since i was getting NotImplementedError butt after installing espeak.exe it works. Yet voice is kind of weird and fast and also i dont really know what languages does plyer support

Any help with plyer TTS or any other module i should use for my Android APK would be appreciated